# Question about Functions of Several Random Variables

Tags: distributions, random-variable, calculus

In the Mathematical Statistics and Data Analysis by John Rice, it states that for random variables $U,V$ which are functions of random variables $X,Y$, we have:

We know that $$f_{UV}(u,v) = f_{XY}(h_1(u,v),h_2(u,v)) |J^{-1}(h_1(u,v),h_2(u,v))|$$

where $h_1(u,v)=x$ and $h_2(u,v)=y$

What doesn't make sense to me is this:

If $f_{XY}(x,y) = x$ (i.e. it doesn't depend on $y$), and we let $U=X^2$ and $V=Y^2$, then $|J^{-1}(h_1(u,v),h_2(u,v))|=4xy = 4\sqrt{uv} $, which has $v$ in it.

And thus $f_{UV}(u,v)$ has $v$ in it. But clearly from my construction, $f_{UV}(u,v)$ shouldn't depend on $v$.

What am I doing incorrectly here?

Comment: Nothing wrong: $f_{XY}(x,y)$ also involves $y$ by a constraint on its support, like $\mathbb I_{(0,1)}(y)$ and a Uniform distribution on $Y$ does not turn into a Uniform distribution on $Y^2$.